# Update V-if in vuejs reactively

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I was wondering if it's possible to re-render this v-if statement inside my component.

I am enabling/disabling a user account through firebase admin functions. This currently works, however whenever I disable a user I have to refresh the page in order to show updates, I can manually refresh, but wondered if there is a way to do this with reactivity? I've tried to update the array manually (UsersAuth contains all the users from Firebase, with the disabled: true|false boolean).

html

```
<span v-if="usersAuth[index].disabled === true"> <button type="button" v-on:click="enableUser(user.id, index)" class="btn btn-success">Enable</button></span>
<span v-if="usersAuth[index].disabled === false"><button type="button" v-on:click="disableUser(user.id)" class="btn btn-primary">Disable</button></span>
```

VueJS Methods

```
  data () {
    return {
      users: [],
      user: null,
      usersAuth: null,
      selecteduser: null
    }
  },
 created () {
    // call all users from the firebase store.
    const addMessage = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('listAllUsers')
    addMessage()
      .then(result => {
        this.usersAuth = result.data.users
      })

    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      this.user = user
    })

    this.users = []
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection('roles')
      .get()
      .then(snap => {
        snap.forEach(doc => {
          const user = doc.data()
          console.log(doc.data())
          user.id = doc.id
          this.users.push(user)
        })
      })
    // get the users' enabled status
  },
   disableUser (uid) {
      const addMessage = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('disableUser')
      const data = { uid: uid }
      addMessage(data)
        .then((result) => {
          if (result === true) {
            console.log(this.userAuth)
          }
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error)
        })
    },
    enableUser (uid, index) {
      const addMessage = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('enableUser')
      const data = { uid: uid }
      addMessage(data)
        .then((result) => {
           this.usersAuth[index].disabled = true
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error)
        })
    },

listAllUsers () {
      const addMessage = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('listAllUsers')
      addMessage()
        .then((result) => {
          console.log(result)
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error)
        })
    }
```

Firebase function (if you require this)

```
exports.disableUser = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {

  if (!context.auth.token.superadmin) return
  try {
    listUsers = admin.auth().updateUser(data.uid, {
      disabled: true
    })

    .then(function() {
      console.log("Successfully disabled user " + data.uid);
      })

    return true
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }

});

exports.enableUser = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {

  if (!context.auth.token.superadmin) return
  try {
    listUsers = admin.auth().updateUser(data.uid, {
      disabled: false
    })

    .then(function() {
      console.log("Successfully disabled user " + data.uid);
      })

    return true
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }

});

exports.listAllUsers = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {

  if (!context.auth.token.superadmin) return

  try {
  return admin.auth().listUsers()
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
});
```

Comment: So, even with manually setting the server-side changes (with this.usersAuth[index].disabled = true, I can't use VueJs reactivity to update the Dom?

Comment: Shouldn't `this.usersAuth[index].disabled = true` in `enableUser` be `this.usersAuth[index].disabled = false`?

Comment: Omg im an idiot, it works now! Ty

Comment: Also suggest you read this post about forceRendering https://michaelnthiessen.com/force-re-render/ also whenever you feel you're breaking reactivity, try rewriting to solve the problem, you might be confused and are using inappropriate solution to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

In your `enableUser` method, `this.usersAuth[index].disabled = true` should be `this.usersAuth[index].disabled = false`, so that you're enabling the user rather than disabling them.

You can read [The Vue Instance](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Data-and-Methods) and [Reactivity in Depth](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html) for more information about how reacitivty works with Vue.

> When a Vue instance is created, it adds all the properties found in
> its data object to Vue’s reactivity system. When the values of those
> properties change, the view will “react”, updating to match the new
> values.

On a side note, if `disabled` is either `true` or `false`, you can simplify your code to:

`<span v-if="usersAuth[index].disabled">`
and `<span v-else>`